# Routing when using api controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i am really frustrated and dont know why i cannot route to my specified page like

`<a href="{{ route('profile') }}"> profile </a>`

i am using an api controller and this is my controller and i am trying just to return a view

```
public function profile()
    {
      return view('layouts.main');
    }
```

as simple as thats it just to return a view , all it does is that it reloads my welcome page

please i need your assistance

here is my api controller

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);
Route::get('profile', 'API\UserController@profile')->name('profile');
Route::put('profile', 'API\UserController@updateProfile');
Route::get('findUser', 'API\UserController@search');

Route::apiResources(['service' => 'API\ServiceController']);
```

Comment: Show us the route.php or api.php where your route is defined and please make sure you read all information in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Comment: Why are you returning a `view` from an `API` route/controller?

Comment: @Peppermintology i am returning a view in this case because i already have a route in my api controller that leads to the view page i want

Comment: @EmilGeorgiev my api controller is above

Comment: You don't return views from an API endpoint, you return data in format such as JSON or XML.

Comment: @Peppermintology so what happens when you want to return views, do I have to necessary create another controller?

Comment: Typically if you're developing an app which has both `Web` and `API` routes, you would namespace the controllers which service the routes. Your `API` routes would mimic your `Web` routes just with the `api` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in your `api.php`

**for laravel 8**

```
Route::resource("/users",UserController::class);
```

Than the routes will be automatically prefixed with `/api`. So the routes will look like this:

```
 /api/users
    /api/users/{user}
    ...
```

So you just have to suppose that the api prefix, is automatically added from `routes/api.php`.

but if you put it in your `web.php`

```
Route::resource("/users",UserController::class);
```

the routes will look like this:

```
  {{ route('users.index') }}
     {{ route('users.profile') }}
        ...
```

for create an action like profile you have to make that:

```
Route::resourse('profile',[UserController::class,'profile')->name('profile');
```

For more information about your routes, you can run `php artisan route:list` and you can check how do your routes look like.

Comment: thanks @Mhammed this is what i have in my api.php `Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);`  isnt that the same as `Route::resource("/users",UserController::class);` ?

Comment: yeah, `Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);` don't have `create` and `edit` action .